# MySQLi Select sum column order by day week

Tags: php, mysqli

I have table:

```
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

I need to have in result:
Total amount order by weekdays.
**Email**: test@mail.ru
**Monday** : 100
**Tuesday** : 33
**Wednesday** : 3461
**Thursday**: 0
**Friday** : 238
**Saturday** : 746
**Sunday** : 74
.....
Please help me to build query)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a SQL query to solve your problem:

```
SELECT DAYNAME(created_date) as weekd, count(id) as cnt
FROM yourTable 
WHERE created_date BETWEEN '2017-07-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-08-01 00:00:00'
GROUP BY weekd
```

The [DAYNAME()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-dayname-function.php) function defines the names of the day of the week. Using [GROUP BY](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) will group by the day names. At the same time using **COUNT()** is the number of orders for each name of the day of the week.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(amount)
FROM (
    SELECT amount FROM table ORDER BY weekend
);
```